# How do I create a default association for files with an unknown extension in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7

It used to be possible to set `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\Shell\Open\Command` and then any unknown files would open with the specified program instead of seeing that “Open With...” dialog box.

This applies to files with no extension, as well as files with `.dat` or `.xyz` or whatever.

This page explains how:  [Vim Tip 185](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/VimTip185)

Does Windows 7 let you do this?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's still possible to do it this way. However, you must also set the default command for the `Unknown` key. By default is probably `openas`, but you can change it. Just set `HKEY_CLASSES_ROOT\Unknown\shell` default value to `Open`.

Also, when you change `HKCR` keys those writes will be directed to their actual location, which is `HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\Software\Classes`. If there exists the same keys in the corresponding per-user location (`HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes`) then that value will be used instead- just changing the `HKCR` value isn't enough, you'll need to change the `HKCU` value as well.

Answer (score 2):

Based on [Factor Mystic's](https://superuser.com/users/270/factor-mystic) answer, I was able to do this in a way that only requires changing `HKCU`.  I did not want to affect any other users on the device, since I share it with other people.

Here is my file named `unknown-files.reg`:

```
Windows Registry Editor Version 5.00

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Unknown]
@="Unknown file"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Unknown\shell]
@="open"

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Unknown\shell\open]

[HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Classes\Unknown\shell\open\command]
@="c:\\Windows\\write.exe \"%1\""
```

Just be sure to have `open` as the default value under the `shell` folder, and also provide the `"%1"` after the program's path so it will know which file to open.